# How can I delete certain area using iter in python

Tags: java, python

In Java, There is `iter.remove()` method.
It has advantage for time complexity when I remove while iterating in LinkedList.

Exam code:

```
    B = [[4,1],[4,2]]
    list = [[1,2,3,4,5] , ... , [5,2,3,5,2]]
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for(Iterator<List<Integer>> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            List<Integer> out = iter.next();
            if(Math.min(out.get(0), out.get(2)) <= B[i][0] && B[i][0] <= Math.max(out.get(0), out.get(2))) {
                iter.remove();
                if(max < out.get(4)) {
                    max = out.get(4);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
```

In this code, time complexity is O(n). because it's linked list and using iterator when removing

So I want to implement this code in python. but I couldn't find `iter.remove()` in python. There is only way using FP, deque(also take n^2 time) and `list.remove(value)`.. is there any way to make it in python?

Comment: No. Python iterators are considerably more general than Java Iterators, and do not necessarily have an underlying Collection to remove an element from.  It looks like a generator may make more sense for this problem in Python, could you be a little clearer about what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I wanna know there is a method to remove what iterator point out directly in python..

Comment: There is no `Iterator.remove` equivalent in Python.

Comment: Also Python lists aren't linked lists, and there would be no time complexity advantage to a `remove` method for Python list iterators. Making a new list is usually the most efficient option.

Comment: Thanks for y'all!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, Python's deque.remove() and list.remove() are both O(n).